# NullPointerException when accessing class.getResources()

Tags: java, sql, nullpointerexception

I have default package, within it I have one class MyClass.java, and two SQL scripts: createTables.sql, DropTables.sql. I created unit tests for MyClass, it is in same package, where I want access my sql scripts. When I do:

```
MyClass.class.getResources("createTables.sql");
```

I get only `null`. Any ideas how can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure the files are being copied to wherever you're running from? For example, if you've got a jar file, does that include the sql files?

Comment: See if the following helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222023/use-of-java-lang-class-getresources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This obviously happens because your resource cannot be found. Check where it is. If it is in the same directory where your class is your line should work. However if it is in root directory add leading slash: `MyClass.class.getResources("/createTables.sql");`. If the SQL file located in other path write the path carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the / :

```
MyClass.class.getResources("/createTables.sql");
```

Comment: Because the path is relative to the classpath root. So if he doesn't provide an absolute path (or the full path), this is looking in the same package as the class (and I don't think that the .sql is located in the class' package)